# Work around for z-index to have fixed header

Tags: css, z-index

So everything looks fine and works correctly except when you scroll down where the thumbnails are and the left bar is directly across from the thumbnail you can't select them... I know that the z-index div is covering it and thats the reason I can't select them but I need to figure out how to work around this but I can't seem to figure it out. Maybe a jquery solution?

http://originalpenguinaccessories.com/midwest/

Updated with a sample...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
#headerContainer {
width: 100%;
position:fixed;
z-index:9999;
display:inline;
}
#topbar {
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
background-color: #004570;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(100, 100, 100, .9);
box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(100, 100, 100, .9);
}
#logo {
background-color: #004570;
height: 360px;
width: 250px;
margin-left: 50px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
display: inline-block;
-webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(100, 100, 100, .9);
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(100, 100, 100, .9);
}
#logo img {
margin-top: 30px;
margin-left: 15px;
}
#logo h2 {
    margin-top: 100px;
    color: white;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
#link {
    background-color: #004570;
    float: right;
    width: 135px;
    height: 55px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 40px;
    color: white;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 15px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(100, 100, 100, .9);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(100, 100, 100, .9);
}
#link p {
    font-size: .8em;
}
#contentContainer {
    width: 40%;
}

</style>


</head>

<body>
<div id="headerContainer">
    <div id="topbar"></div>
    <div id="logo">
    <img src="" alt="">
     <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h2>

</div>
<div id="link">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
     <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h6>

</div>
</div>
<div id="contentContainer">
 <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <div class="image-grid">
    <div class="imageDiv"> <a href="images/thumb.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">Link</a>

         <h4>M442</h4>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageDiv"> <a href="images/thumb.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">Link</a>

         <h4>M442</h4>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageDiv"> <a href="images/thumb.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">Link</a>

         <h4>M442</h4>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="imageDiv"> <a href="images/thumb.jpg" rel="lightbox" title="my caption">Link</a>

         <h4>M442</h4>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
</div>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: haha... I dont think you read my question below... How can I work around this issue...

Comment: I guess you didn't read the link I give you. Your question is going to be closed as too localized if you just paste a link here. Click my link, read it and add back relevant codes to your question.

Comment: Updated... Sorry I didn't see the link. It just looked like you said it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply `position:absolute` to your `#logo` and `#link` divs (and `right:0` for the `#link`). This will take them out of the element flow and the parent div will collapse.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
#logo {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}

.fs-pager-wrapper {
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Comment: won't help since 1) the parent z-index is relevant. 2) Not the logo itself is overlapping but the parent container.